# Does a .string label in x86 add null termination?

Tags: x86, label, gnu-assembler, att

Does this code add a null ascii value in the byte after the byte storing the last character in the string?

```
label: .string "word"
```

Comment: A _label_ itself does not add any terminal character. But if the `.string` directive does add one after the last character depends on your assembler - which you didn't specify.

Comment: IIRC yes, `.string` is a synonym for `.asciz` (not `.ascii`) in GAS.  You could easily check by putting that line in a file by itself and assembling + disassembling it to see the hexdump.